# [head_camera] does not match name narrow_stereo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed the `usb_cam` driver, and I can got the viedo stream through launch file. But the terminal told

```
[head_camera] does not match name narrow_stereo in file /home/michael/.ros/camera_info/head_camera.yaml.
```

what is that? How can I solve it? below is my `.yaml` file:

```
image_width: 640
image_height: 480
camera_name: narrow_stereo
camera_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [653.558145, 0, 315.474744, 0, 612.170158, 246.740547, 0, 0, 1]
distortion_model: plumb_bob
distortion_coefficients:
  rows: 1
  cols: 5
  data: [0.071946, -0.127256, 0.003988999999999999, -0.008007, 0]
rectification_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 3
  data: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
projection_matrix:
  rows: 3
  cols: 4
  data: [660.515259, 0, 310.741637, 0, 0, 621.001221, 247.869777, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256547/%5Bhead_camera%5D-does-not-match-name-narrow_stereo/) by [michael_kong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29170/michael_kong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally find the solution :change" camera_name: narrow_stereo" to "camera_name: head_camera", yeah in your project, the "head_camera" maybe other names, but just change it into a correct one.

---

Originally posted by [michael_kong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29170/michael_kong/) with karma: 41 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1